# Can't change parent page

Tags: pages, homepage, child-pages

Some of my pages are children of "home". I want to assign them to a new page. But I cant change the pages parent. Everytime I try and publish, it just switches back to "home".

I am using the Roots-Theme, I don't know if that matters.

Edit: I even tried to erase "Home". The children of home are assigned to "Main" then (I could not change that either). As I recreated home, they were reassigned to it. Maybe its because of the WPML Multilanguage plugin?

Comment: Please report after clearing browser's cache. And also let's know if you have any caching plugin enabled, that's active in your admin panel.

Comment: Clearing cache made no difference. I'm not using a caching plugin.

Comment: What about choosing `"Main Page (no-parent)"` for once and saving the page; then selecting your desired parent page and saving again? Does it work for you?

Comment: No, I cant choose Main, Home is always the parent page.

Comment: Would you please list some of your home pages, what you have in your theme: `index.php`, `front-page.php`, `home.php`, etc?

Comment: index.php, page.php and some custom templates, on of it page-home.php is the homepage. How does that affect the nesting of pages?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this problem only in phpMyAdmin.

Shortly: find the child page in the table 'wp_posts' and change the value of 'post_parent' to 0 (zero).

Step by step:

1. Browse the table 'wp_posts', find the child page by title (post_title) or whatever else attribute. Be sure it isn't a revision (check it in 'post_status' column).
2. Click the pen in the beginning of this row to edit and find the 'post_parent' row, currently 6th from bottom. It must have the parent page ID in the cell. Change the value to 0 (zero).
3. Before clicking the 'Go' button in the bottom, be sure 'Save' is selected in the drop-down menu in the left. It should be by default.

Hope this helps.

It is possible this bug is caused by WPML Multilingual CMS plugin.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like this ia better solution: http://wpml.org/forums/topic/cannot-change-the-parent-page-since-wpml-2-7/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone.